# Visual Studio 2010 - automatic git commit, push when file is saved

Tags: visual-studio-2010, git

Is there a way to have Visual Studio 2010 automatically commit a file and push it to a git repository when the file is saved?

I would like to be able to have a pop up box appear to allow me to write the commit message on save. I feel that this would force some good habits on me, because sadly I can miss a day or ten of commits on occasion and as I am the sole developer this isn't a job requirement here.

Comment: You'll soon get fed up with a prompt coming up every time you save a file.

Comment: @TheZ I might, but its my own laziness I need to change, so consider it penance.

Comment: @RobertH You're laziness is going to hurt you more than that. The rule number zero of every version control is "always have a buildable repository".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a configuration manager point of view I completely disagree with your "always commit" policy.

Insted, I don't know if have you tried [Visual Local History 2005](http://vlh2005.codeplex.com/). I've used it in the 2005 and 2008 versions, but I've never tried with the 2010 version. It simply create a subdirectory and save there a local copy every save you make. So you could watch the history per-file.

**THEN** you could commit at the right point (when it really makes sense).

Let me know if it works as you would.

Comment: Robert H, if you think I've answered correctly, please let me know :)